# How to set decimal precision in OData

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, odata

I am trying to round decimal property using scale, but it is not working

```
public class Student 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Decimal { get; set; } = 0.000000m;
}

builder.EntitySet<Student>("Student");

var student = builder.EntityType<Student>();
student.Property(s => s.Decimal).Scale = 2;
```

Request: https://localhost:44383/OData/Student

Result is:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://localhost:44383/OData/$metadata#Student",
    "value": [
        {
            "Decimal": 0.000000,
            "Id": "efb93e81-2729-40e2-bd0b-44dc338217f9"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am expecting the result will be

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://localhost:44383/OData/$metadata#Student",
    "value": [
        {
            "Decimal": 0.00,
            "Id": "efb93e81-2729-40e2-bd0b-44dc338217f9"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I fix it?

**EDIT**:

Adding `Precision` also didn't help:

```
 builder.EntityType<Student>().Property(s => s.Decimal).Precision = 2;
```

Comment: I think what you want to use is precision instead of scale

Comment: @phonemyatt, I tried precision, but it didn't work

Comment: what if you use both, precision = 3, scale = 2. or you can try with data annotation like  [Column(TypeName = "decimal(3, 2)")]

Comment: @phonemyatt Tried but they are not working

Comment: Hi @DIlshodK,why not change `public decimal Decimal { get; set; } = 0.000000m;` to `public decimal Decimal { get; set; } = 0.00m;`?

Comment: @Rena Why should I change it? The problem is in scale not in property. When I load entity from database the value become as  0.000000m. I allowed 6 zeros in database, but in client it should show only two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it is source code issue: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/2384. Workarround:

```
    public static decimal CalculateDecimalPrecision(decimal value, int precision)
    {
        if (ShouldCalculatePrecision(value, precision, out bool shouldRound))
        {
            if (shouldRound)
            {
                value = Math.Round(value, precision);
            }
            else
            {
                var calculatedPrecision = decimal.Divide(1, Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Pow(10, precision)));
                var zeroAfterPoint = calculatedPrecision - calculatedPrecision;
                value += zeroAfterPoint;
            }
        }
        return value;
    }

public class CustomODataPrimitiveSerializer : ODataPrimitiveSerializer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Rewriting decimal value
    /// </summary>
    public override ODataPrimitiveValue CreateODataPrimitiveValue(object graph, IEdmPrimitiveTypeReference primitiveType, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)
    {
        if (graph is decimal decimalValue && primitiveType is EdmDecimalTypeReference decimalTypeReference && decimalTypeReference.Scale != null)
        {
            graph = CalculateDecimalPrecision(decimalValue, decimalTypeReference.Scale.Value);
        }
        return base.CreateODataPrimitiveValue(graph, primitiveType, writeContext);
    }
}
```