# ASP.NET Core OData - filter on datetime with milliseconds not working?

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-odata

I'm using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData` version 7.5.14.

I'm trying to execute something like this:

```
"$filter=cast(START_TIME, Edm.DateTimeOffset) eq 2022-04-13T13:55:55.107Z"
```

(or `ge`, or `le`, for that matter)

Because of the milliseconds, this fails. That date exists in the database, yet I get 0 records returned.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT:  More information:**

I can query that value in SQL Server Mgmt Studio.  No problem.

I can use this odata:

```
"$filter=START_TIME eq 2022-04-13T13:55:55.107-04:00"
```

-4:00 is the UTC of the server.

The above fails (cast to DateTimeOffset) as it's using this precision:

```
"$filter=cast(START_TIME, Edm.DateTimeOffset) eq 2022-04-13T13:55:55.1070000Z"
```

Which won't match the database value.  I wanted to use DateTimeOffset as it adds time zone information relative to UTC.

Comment: To me it seems odd you would want to filter based on a time stamp down to the millisecond. How did you get that time stamp to begin with? A more common use case would be to filter by range (provide a start and end datetime and get values between them). That all said I am not sure about that cast to Edm.DateTimeOffset, that looks wrong to me but maybe you have some magic you are not showing us or maybe I am not aware of that feature. Finally you should profile your DB to see what the actual query is that is executed, maybe that gives you a hint on why you are getting 0 records.

Comment: Well, when you don't know anything about the software, it would seem odd, right?  We allow the user to filter on ANY field.  And we allow them to choose things like less than, less than or equal, greater than, greater than or equal, equal, not equal, etc.  On top of that if they want to see values in the database, we give them a browse feature that gives them (paginated) distinct values for that column.  And this particular field will have milliseconds.  So, when a user selects equal, and a field that is datetime, and a value with millis. And it doesn't work.  Well, they and I want to know why

Comment: And it works worse without the cast.  Things like greater than or less than, that don't even require us to match exactly, don't work at all.  The cast makes things work, and i freely admit I don't entirely understand why.  Well, everything but equals, because it ignores milliseconds.

Comment: Got it. Profile the DB and capture what values are being used. Hopefully that sheds some light on why the results are not the ones you expect.

Comment: If possible, could you please inform us what exact value you have passed as a parameter and what value you are getting after casting it? You could try to print the values somewhere. It could help to know whether there is any difference in the value.

Comment: Looking at the profiler, it's adding four extra zeroes.  Therefore, the profiler thinks it's trying to do an equal on .1070000Z.  So we are looking to figure out a way to set the precision using odata.  I've read in the odata documentation this exact line: "Edm.DateTimeOffset, Edm.Duration, and Edm.TimeOfDay values can be cast to the same type with a different precision with appropriate rounding", but have found no examples.

Comment: I would suggest you refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65878710/10309381) it may help you get some code examples.